# How to submit a correction to Timatic?

Tags: timatic

If I believe that I've found an error in Timatic---for example, it claims that a particular document is not required, but I believe that the document *is* required under applicable laws and regulations---is there any way to ask them to consider making a correction?

Comment: It may also be appropriate to contact the authorities of the country involved, as they would be the primary source of the information. Depending on the country, this may or may not be straightforward, though. Out of curiosity, what is the correction?

Comment: @jcaron The United Airlines interface to Timatic suggests that travellers to the US who hold an advance parole document are exempt from presenting a passport, and I believe that this information is contradicted by both CBP and USCIS.

Comment: @Brian It's correct, parole holers (incl. EAD cards endorsed I-512) don't need a passport. The TIMATIC team strongly dislike correction requests not backed up by individual correspondence from the border authorities

Comment: @Crazydre What is your source for this claim? [USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/travel-documents) says that the AP can substitute for a visa, but "does not replace your passport".

Comment: @Brian E-mail the CBP and they will confirm this to you. Put mark.a.morgan@cbp.dhs.gov, robert.e.perez@cbp.dhs.gov, edward.e.young@cbp.dhs.gov and todd.c.owen@cbp.dhs.gov as recipients, and start the message with "**Please forward to the person/department liaising with the IATA TIMATIC team**" then share your concerns as clearly as possible.

Comment: @Crazydre well, if what you say is correct, then TIMATIC does not need any changes. I guess I will just email them and express my concerns that the CBP website does not state this clearly.

Comment: @Brian You'd be surprised that the relevant web editing department will likely be mis-informed of the rules. The US is one of the countries where accurate knowledge of specific rules within governmental bodies is often inadequate (can be observed in field operations as well, not least with regards to NEXUS cards being a passport exemption when flying Canada <-> US), and it's always the main management of the *operational* body (CBP) that should be consulted.

Comment: @Crazydre I just called CBP at JFK airport, and they told me that a passport is required. When I pressed them about it, they said that if I happen to have lost my passport on the plane, they could look up the passport information based on the advance parole, but the passport still needs to be valid, even if I don't have it in my possession. Perhaps if I email them, they'll give me a different answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109699/discussion-between-brian-and-crazydre).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a contact page on the [Timatic web 2](https://www.timaticweb2.com/contact) website:

> **Do you experience any technical problem, have any invoicing questions, content related issues or need more information about your subscription status?**
>
> Please contact our Customer Service via [www.iata.org/cs](http://www.iata.org/cs)

On the IATA website, it looks like you need to use the *Customer Portal*:

> The IATA Customer Portal is packed with useful services, product information, useful tips and tricks specially tailored to you. **You can use it to contact our Customer Service Team easily**, including live chat or directly purchase from our online store.

You can create an account [here](https://portal.iata.org/s/login/SelfRegister?language=en_US).

It is preferred to have solid evidence to back it up (preferably an e-mail from the actual border authority)

Comment: That said, the suggested error is in fact not an error

Comment: There is the email address timediting@iata.org, but again, they dislike requests from the public, so one had ***damn better*** be clear about what is being questioned, **and** have solid evidence to back it up (preferably an e-mail from the actual border authority). After I myself sent a number of successful requests, I was assigned the sourcing manager as a contact person and now exclusively liaise with him

Comment: So I guess the full answer to this question is that the customer portal should be used, and additionally one should include a copy of an email from the responsible immigration authorities. Perhaps that detail should be edited into the answer?

Comment: @Brian edited, yes you are correct